# Understanding Thread/BeginInvoke? [beginner]

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, begininvoke

Consider the code:

```
class Work
{
    public void DoStuff(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        // .. whatever
    }
}
class Master
{
    private readonly Work work = new Work();

    public void Execute()
    {
        string hello = "hello";

        // (1) is this an ugly hack ?
        var thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(o => this.work.DoStuff((string)o)));           
        thread1.Start(hello);
        thread1.Join();

        // (2) is this similar to the one above?
        new Action<string>(s => this.work.DoStuff(s)).BeginInvoke(hello, null, null);
    }
}
```

Is (1) an acceptable way of easy starting some work in a seperate thread? If not a better alternative would be much appreciated.

Is (2) doing the same? I guess what I ask is if a new thread is started, or..

Hope you can help a beginner to a better understanding  :)

/Moberg

Comment: There is a great article here: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/02/24/asyncdelegates.html that explains the nuances between Threads and asynchronous delegates.

Comment: Using something as expensive as a thread and then wasting it away with Thread.Join is *not* acceptable.  There are many resources to help you choose between Thread and a threadpool thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(1) is not an ugly hack, but it is not "the" way of doing threads these days.  [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx) threads via [`BeginInvoke/EndInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx), [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) in .NET 4.0 are the way to go.

(2) is good, BUT you need to pair your `BeginInvoke` with an `EndInvoke` somewhere.  Assign the new `Action<string>` to a variable and then call `x.EndInvoke()` manually on it in your main thread or in a completion method (2nd parameter to `BeginInvoke`).  See [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml) as a decent reference.

Edit: here's how (2) should look to be reasonably equivalent to (1):

```
    var thread2 = new Action<string>(this.work.DoStuff);
    var result = thread2.BeginInvoke(hello, null, null);
    thread2.EndInvoke(result);
```